# Python sum with condition using a date and a condition

Tags: python, pandas, date, sum

I have to dataframes and I am using pandas.
I want to do a cumulative sum from a variable date and by the value in a column

I want to add a second column to df2 that show the date to know the day when the sum of the AVG column is greater than 100 after date2 in df2.

For example with df1 and df2 being the dataframe I start with and df3 what I want and df3['date100'] is the day the sum of avg is greater than 100:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date1': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014', '3/1/2014','1/1/2014', '2/1/2014', '3/1/2014','1/1/2014', '2/1/2014', '3/1/2014'],
 'Place':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],'AVG': [62,14,47,25,74,60,78,27,41]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date2': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014'], 'Place':['A','C'])})

*Something*
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date2': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014'], 'Place':['A','C'], 'date100': ['3/1/2014', '2/1/2014'], 'sum': [123, 105]})
```

I found some answers but most them use groupby and df2 has no groups.

Comment: I don't understand the relation of the first df2 with the operation you want to do.

Comment: I am summing the column from that day, so for the second element in df2 [2/1/2014] I do 14+47+25+74.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your example is very basic, if you have edge cases you want me to take care of, just ask. This solution implies that :

The solution :

```
#   For this solution your DataFrame needs to be sorted by date.
limit = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date1': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014', '3/1/2014','1/1/2014',
              '2/1/2014', '3/1/2014','1/1/2014', '2/1/2014', '3/1/2014'], 
    'Place':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
    'AVG': [62,14,47,25,74,60,78,27,41]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date2': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014'], 'Place':['A','C']})

result = []
for row in df2.to_dict('records'):
    #   For each date, I want to select the date that comes AFTER this one.
    #   Then, I take the .cumsum(), because it's the agg you wish to do.
    #   Filter by your limit and take the first occurrence.
    #   Converting this to a dict, appending it to a list, makes it easy
    #   to rebuild a DataFrame later.
    ndf = df.loc[ (df['date1'] >= row['date2']) & (df['Place'] == row['Place']) ]\
            .sort_values(by='date1')
    ndf['avgsum'] = ndf['AVG'].cumsum()
    final_df = ndf.loc[ ndf['avgsum'] >= limit ]

    #   Error handling, in case there is not avgsum above the threshold.
    try:
        final_df = final_df.iloc[0][['date1', 'avgsum']].rename({'date1' : 'date100'})
        result.append( final_df.to_dict() )
    except IndexError:
        continue

df3 = pd.DataFrame(result)

final_df = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1, sort=False)
print(final_df)
#       date2 Place  avgsum   date100
# 0  1/1/2014     A   123.0  3/1/2014
# 1  2/1/2014     C     NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks it works but my data is not sorted. I also want to know if it's possible go further because in reality I have something like this: df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014', '3/2/2014','4/2/2014','5/2/2014'], 'AVG': [15,14,47,25,74], 'Place':['A','A','B,'C','A'}) and df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date2': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014'], 'Place':['A','C'}). Is it possible to cumsum only the columns 'Place' match?

Comment: It is but I'm not in front of my computer. I think you should have asked that beforehand though because now you're asking 2 questions. I'll try to answer when I am in front of one, but you should be able to do it using a simple loc with the condition you want to filter. :)

Comment: Yes I've realised that now. I tried to use .loc but I can't make it work.

Comment: @yyzzz you should edit your first post with the real **final** question

Comment: Done. I have also put my data in an comment I made to Serge Ballesta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145971/python-sum-with-condition-using-a-date-and-a-condition#comment97054860_55147331)

Comment: @yyzzz I updated my answer. As you can see, your data needn't be sorted anymore & it doesn't need to have positive match in your df2. Be warned though that on big data, this might be long to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But I am not sure to understand what you do. Why do you need `dates = df2['date2'].tolist()` if you don't use it after and what does `(df['Place'] == row['Place'][0])`do?

Comment: @yyzzz You're right, the index [0] was useless and the variable `dates` was legacy and useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct solution, with following assumptions:

- `df1` is sorted by date
- one solution exists for every date in `df2`

You can then do:

```
df2 = df2.join(pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[df1.date1 >= d].AVG.cumsum()).query('AVG>=100')
                .iloc[0]).transpose()
        for d in df2.date2]).rename_axis('ix').reset_index())\
    .join(df1.drop(columns='AVG'), on='ix').rename(columns={'AVG': 'sum', 'date1': 'date100'})\
    .drop(columns='ix')[['date2', 'date100', 'sum']]
```

This does the following:

- for each date in `df2` find the first date when the cumul on AVG will be at least 100
- combine the results in one single dataframe indexed by the index of that line in `df1`
- store that index in an `ix` column and reset the index to join that dataframe to df2
- join that to df1 minus the `AVG` column using the `ix` column
- rename the columns, remove the `ix` column, and re-order everything

Comment: Thanks !  I also want to know if it's possible go further because in reality I have something like this: df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014', '3/2/2014','4/2/2014','5/2/2014'], 'AVG': [15,14,47,25,74], 'Place':['A','A','B,'C','A'}) and df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date2': ['1/1/2014', '2/1/2014'], 'Place':['A','C'}). Is it possible to cumsum only the columns 'Place' match?

Comment: @yyzzz: Adding a condition on Place is not a problem. The real problem is that there is no solution for second date from `df2`, while it was one of my assumptions.

Comment: In practice one solution for every date will always exist

Comment: @yyzzz: could you give a realist example of the input data?